# How to pass a Variable from a Windows Form to an exe

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am trying to pass a ComputerName variable to an exe that my Windows Form opens with a button click. The user enters the hostname into `$ComputerName.Text` box. When they click a button it should run a remote command to that hostname in `$ComputerName.Text`. Right now my exe prompts for an input via Read-host. I would like for it to just grab the variable in the text box.

I am able to run Remote Control Viewer this way by just adding the variable to the end of the line:

```bsh
Start-Process -filepath "*\RemoteViewer\CmRcViewer.exe" $ComputerName.Text
```

I tried changing my remote exe to run off of `$ComputerName.Text` instead of the variable I set in `Read-Host`.

Start of my remote command exe:

```bsh
$ComputerName = Read-host "Enter IP Address or Host Name"
$Computer = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Computersystem -ComputerName $ComputerName).Name
```

Function that starts a remote process:

```bsh
Start-Process -filepath "*remoteprocess.exe" -ArgumentList $ComputerName.Text -WindowStyle Maximized
```

I would like my exe to grab the `$ComputerName.Text` variable and run it on a button click.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the question. Are you trying to pass the `$ComputerName.Text` variable to Remote Control Viewer? I'd assume the `remoteprocess.exe` requires a specific parameter to take `$ComputerName.Text`.

Comment: I am trying to pass $ComputerName.Text to another .exe I have made in powershell. The reason it is a exe is so no one can edit the powershell script I made it in. 

I want $ComputerName.Text to pass to my exe (powershell script turned into an exe) and run my remote command based off the input for $ComputerName.Text

Comment: Did you define `$args[]` in your exe you created? If you don't define arguments within your script then it will not take arguments.

Comment: How did you convert the script to an exe? Is it transpiled or did you just rename the script file to exe?

Comment: How do I define the $args[] in the exe? I used Microsofts powershell to exe script.